# create a GUI in MATLAB that show images in an axes one by one on one time button click using timer

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing

i want to create a GUI in MATLAB that show images in an  axes  one by one on  one time button click with a time span
suppose there is an image and i am using some functions that are to convert that image to grayscale,binary,rgb.I want that all those image after conversion will be displayed on that axes that i created on gui with a single click.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLao2.jpg)

```
MyImage=imread('C:\Users\Omm\Desktop\ZjSqKcW.jpg','Parent',handles.axes1);
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);
hold on;
%Read Image

% Show image
% Objects extraction
%figure(1)
imshow(MyImage);
title('INPUT IMAGE WITH NOISE')

% Convert to gray scale
 % RGB image
    image=rgb2gray(MyImage);
    hold off;
  %figure(2) 
    imshow(image);
```

like this and want that image after each conversion will be shown on that axes itself without clicking on button 
please help me to do this functioning i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try calling the [pause](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html) function before showing each modified image, specifying, as input parameter, the time (in seconds) you want to wait before next image will be displayed.

You also have to slightly modify your code as follows:

- remove the `'Parent',handles.axes1` input in the call to `imread`
- specify the axes on which to show the image in `imshow`

The updated code:

```
% Remove the "'Parent',handles.axes1" in the call to imread
% MyImage=imread('C:\Users\Omm\Desktop\ZjSqKcW.jpg','Parent',handles.axes1);
MyImage=imread('C:\Users\Omm\Desktop\ZjSqKcW.jpg');
% This set of instructions seems not needed
% % % handles.output = hObject;
% % % guidata(hObject, handles);
% % % hold on;
%Read Image

% Show image
% Objects extraction
%figure(1)
%
% Specify the axes on which to display the image
%
% imshow(MyImage);
imshow(MyImage,'Parent',handles.axes1);
title('INPUT IMAGE WITH NOISE')

% Convert to gray scale
% RGB image
image=rgb2gray(MyImage);
% This instruction seems not needed
%%%hold off;
%figure(2)
%
% Call "pause" to temporarily stop (1 second) the execution of the code
% before displayoing the next image
%
pause(1)
% Display the next image
%
% Specify the axes on which to display the image
%
% imshow(MyImage);
imshow(image,'Parent',handles.axes1);
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: thank you sir it's working sorry for disturbing you again and again but sir suppose if we browse that image from a callback function of button 1 like :[filename, pathname]=uigetfile( {'*.jpg';'*.jpeg';'*.gif';'*.png';'*.bmp'},'Select file'); 
 MyImage = strcat(pathname, filename);                                            global a;
  a=MyImage;                 and i want to convert that image to gray scale by that button 2 like: if isfield(handles,'a')
         readimg=imread(a);
       axes(handles.axes2);   end   imshow(imagen,'Parent',handles.axes2); how to do this?

Comment: Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

??? Undefined function or variable 'a'.

Error in ==> UNTITLED>pushbutton2_Callback at 105
       readimg=imread(a);Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> UNTITLED at 41
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
Error while executing this function :
Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)untitled('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback